# Exchange server doesn't respond to input from openssl client

Tags: macos, exchange, openssl

I'm using openssl s_client to connect to an exchange server.
The exchange server doesn't react to anything I type.
I'm on OSX using the terminal.

```
$ openssl s_client -connect pop.server.com:995
CONNECTED(00000003)
<certificate exchange>
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : RC4-MD5
    Session-ID: <longstring>
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: <longstring>
    Key-Arg   : None
    Start Time: 1384517814
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
+OK The Microsoft Exchange POP3 service is ready.
```

Anything I type now does nothing, it doesn't complain about anything it just ignores everything I enter until eventually it kills the session

```
-ERR Connection is closed. 12
read:errno=0
```

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but just in case someone stumbles upon it like me. The answer is using the openssl option -crlf. This will send both a carriage return and a line feed byte as line seperator when pressing enter.